# Android GLSurfaceView as subview

Tags: android

I'm very new to an Android platform and currently trying figure out why things work this way:

If I create `GLSurfaceView` and add it using the `setContentView` or `addContentView` to an activity everything works fine (`Renderer.onDrawFrame` is called as expected). However if I add my `GLSurfaceView` to another `ViewGroup` (which is then added using `setContentView`) nothing is rendered.

So what is the difference between `addView` and `addContentView` ?

In the end I need to create a custom view with OpenGL rendering in background and some controls on top.

Also what is the point of separating View and ViewGroup? Why not to join them (like it is done in CocoaTouch) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setContentView(View)` sets the parent `View` for an Activity (or dialog etc...).

`addView(View)` adds a `View` to a `ViewGroup`.

`View` and `ViewGroup` are mostly different. `View` is a more specific single entity. It should be used more on one facet of what you are trying to do. `ViewGroup`, however, focuses more on the whole and acts (is) a container and layout organizer for a collection of `View`s.

Can you post all the code related to the GLSurfaceView and how you are setting it as contentView?